# Unetbootin .Deb with all dependencies needed

Tags: 17.04, deb, ubuntu-mate

Ok, so I did a fresh install of Ubuntu 17.04 Zesty. Me, being stupid like I sometimes am, didn't make a Windows 7 bootable USB. Windows was the only way I could get online(tether through pdanet). So I need someone to use an online Linux machine to apt-get the Deb package and dependencies for me so I can dual boot windows. It would be greatly appreciated being the other fastest way would be if I downloaded every single file one-by-one. Thanks!

EDIT: question isn't about creating the USB itself. It's about getting the program and all dependencies in one go.

EDIT 2: This isn't about making the usb its about helping me get the files on an offline machine with the only other device I have has android on it. I literally just need the deb files in an archive. I already know how to use the tools.

Comment: You need to [edit](https://askubuntu.com/posts/950511/edit) and give us **much** more information about your system, your configuration, your plans and what the problem is – we won't be able to help you otherwise.

Comment: Possible duplicate of https://askubuntu.com/questions/974/how-can-i-install-software-or-packages-without-internet-offline

Answer (score 2):

The binary file available for download from https://unetbootin.github.io/linux_download.html is statically linked. You should be able to use it without worrying too much about dependencies.

Comment: Binary loads right but it can't access anything outside of /root

Comment: Eh? Normally applications can't access anything inside `/root`. Post a screenshot.

Comment: I got it to go, but as others have said, unetbootin won't do windows. So could you possibly apt-get -d woeusb and zip it for me? It's all I need and everyone is just trying to make it complicated. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

All the `.deb` files in the package sources can be downloaded from [packages.ubuntu.com](https://packages.ubuntu.com/), in your case it's [this for amd64 (`x86_64`)](https://packages.ubuntu.com/zesty/amd64/unetbootin/download) and [this for i386](https://packages.ubuntu.com/zesty/i386/unetbootin/download). If unsure you can test which one suits your system by executing `arch` or `uname -m` in a terminal.

However, it seems that UNetbootin can't be used to create Windows bootable usb sticks. The simplest way is to use `dd` **with caution!!!** like so:

```
sudo dd if=/path/to/iso/windows.iso of=/dev/sdX bs=4M; sync
```

For more, read [How can I create a Windows bootable USB stick using Ubuntu?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/289559/how-can-i-create-a-windows-bootable-usb-stick-using-ubuntu).

---

Edit: OP now wants `woeusb` together with all its dependencies.

A package's dependencies can be found in its `README` file located in the `.tar.gz`. For `woeusb` it says:

```
$ sudo apt-get install devscripts equivs gdebi-core
```

Now to show the urgent dependencies of **these** packages do:

```
> apt-cache depends --no-suggests --no-recommends --no-breaks --no-replaces devscripts equivs gdebi-core
devscripts
  Depends: dpkg-dev
  Depends: perl
  Depends: <python3:any>
    python3:i386
    python3
  Depends: libc6
equivs
  Depends: perl
  Depends: debhelper
  Depends: dpkg-dev
  Depends: make
    make-guile
  Depends: fakeroot
    fakeroot:i386
    pseudo:i386
    pseudo
gdebi-core
  Depends: <python3:any>
    python3:i386
    python3
  Depends: python3-apt
  Depends: python3-debian
  Depends: file
    file:i386
```

And there you have your list of all the packages you need. I'd test the existing system for these packages, download the ones not installed and install them all at once.

Comment: I was going to use dd but doesn't it need the MBR?

Comment: @TylerLogsdon Not that I know – my [source (German)](https://wiki.ubuntuusers.de/Live-USB/#Manuelle-Erstellung-mittels-dd) doesn't mention any limitations of that method.

Comment: Dd doesn't make it boot.

Comment: You did enable boot from usb in the BIOS and chose the stick as the boot device, did you?

Comment: Yep. But since someone said that unetbootin doesn't work with windows, could someone possibly upload woeusb?

Comment: Why do you insist on someone uploading something that's [available online](https://www.ubuntuupdates.org/package/webupd8/zesty/main/base/woeusb)? I really don't get what you're up to, maybe you should [edit your question](https://askubuntu.com/posts/950511/edit) and explain.

Comment: Because my Linux machine can't get online. The only way I could get it is if I go to the repo and download them one by one(including dependencies) I just want someone to run apt-get -d woeusb and upload the packages so that I don't have to do that.

Comment: @TylerLogsdon `woeusb` is not present in the repos, so `apt-get -d woeusb` won't do anything useful. Additionally, `apt-get -d` just downloads a package, it does nothing with dependencies. See my updated answer for instructions.